# how to use array of images for displaying in imageview and images are in url form

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview

I have array of images and all images are in url form .I want to display in my imageview,which is on uitableviewcell .I am able to show all images but my tableview scrolling is not working properly.
How to solve this problem.
Thanks

Comment: Show some code, you're probably loading the images when the UITableView is requesting a cell which makes the scrolling horribly slow. Images should be fetched on a background thread.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you are fetching a large amount of data also displaying that in the iphone Screen. The User Interface stuck like your tableView is not scrolling. Leon Rodenburg said is absolutely correct just fetch the data on the background thread then gather the result and after that load the User Interface on the main thread.

Threading to start call the method(Use multiple or several method call's):-

```
    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(Method_Name:) toTarget:self withObject:argument1];



    -(void)Method_Name:(NSString*)argument{

Perform Actions and Set Conditions then move to main thread

    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(Loading_User_Interface) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];

    }


    -(void) Loading_User_Interface{

//check condition of all background threads are done.... if condition is fulfilled load the user interface. 

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are getting a load of data it might take a while and lag up. Have you tried dequeuing the cell. It basically makes it nil until you scroll down and see it, it makes the cell reusable with a identifier so when you can't see it it is nil but when you come across it it becomes assigned:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView
                         dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                   reuseIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"]
            autorelease];

      }
```

Implement this in cellForRowAtIndexPath:

Comment: also can fetch data in background thread or sometime before (WHAT coolanilkothari said)